# How to save to a disk an excel file present in c# Resources folder?

Tags: c#

I'm using c# and I have stored report.xls is "Resources" folder as shown in the below image. How can I save this to the disk?

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer specifically for your project setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have added your `report.xls` as a resource file via the project resources:

[image]

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\Somelocation\\report.xls", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    byte[] data = Properties.Resources.report;
    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In above line what is "YourConfigurationFile"? When I add byte[] data = Properties.Resources.App.Config; I'm getting error.

Comment: In your case, that line should be: `byte[] data = Properties.Resources.report;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The problem was I dragged the file to Resources folder.